How to specify which algorithm to check for in Unity keystore manager? Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
Trying to generate an APK from Unity with a keystore file that is generated from a key file generated from android studio. keystore JKS file made with Android studio does not work with Unity when I type in correct password it says wrong password and can not decode it. The error is:
Unable to list keys in the keystore. Please make sure the location and password of the keystore is correct. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\java.exe -Xmx4096M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.20f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\cmdline-tools\6.0" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.20f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

...

stderr[
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Error: Unable to read 'D:\Keys\PlayStoreKEY.jks'
Error: Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available
]
stdout[

]

exit code: 255

The key works with Android studio and with Java keytool. I want it to work with Unity editor and export apk from editor build option.
So how do I specify which algorithm to look for via command or attributes in Unity editor?
